# How to get both generated crud and 'ondelete cascade' using prisma 2 or 3 and nexus schema generation

Tags: node.js, graphql, nexus, prisma

I'm trying to build a node graphql server with nexus and prisma 2 or 3.  I also use the provider="nexus-prisma".   I'm think I have to user prisma-nexus-plugin because it's the only way I know to not have to write lots of crud resolver manually and maintain them (experimentalCrud option).  That requires 2.23.0.  But my problem is that 'referential integrity' in prisma isn't supported until 2.26.0.  is there a better set of library versions that would give me crud and ref-integrity?    Ultimatly I just want to build a decent graphql server from my schema.prisma. (edited)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a new plugin called [nexus-prisma](https://github.com/prisma/nexus-prisma/) which targets the latest version of Prisma. However, as of December 2021, this is still in *early preview* and is not production-ready.

As a possible alternative, [TypeGraphQL](https://typegraphql.com/) also has a [Prisma Plugin](https://github.com/MichalLytek/typegraphql-prisma) which targets recent versions of Prisma (~3.6.0). I haven't used this extensively, but it seems to fit your use case.

Comment: I rebased my project onto a typegraphql example setup I found here:  https://github.com/prisma/prisma-examples/tree/latest/typescript/graphql-typegraphql-crud

Note: the package.json is broken in this example but easily fixed by swapping prisma and prisma-client versions to 3.6.0 and then reinstalling node_modules.  it works well and does indeed autogen the crud resolvers AND support prisma 3.6 'onDelete: Cascade'   Thanks

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help :D